# Cant Open 2 .sln files in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sln-file

I'm trying to open up two .SLN (solution) files in Visual Studio, but whenever I drag one in, the other goes away... Help?

Comment: You can only open 1 solution file at a time - if your goal is to open projects from multiple solutions you can either add them to one of your solutions or create a new solution to add the existing projects to.

Comment: Or, launch two instances of VS

Answer (score 3):

The .sln files are solution files which Visual Studio can only open one of per instance; however, you may open multiple projects (.csproj, .vbproj, etc.) in a single solution if that's what you're wanting to do.